# SQL Split Island On Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have a SQL table with `From` and `To` dates like so:

```
Row    From                    To 
--------------------------------------------------
1      2017-10-28 00:00:00     2017-10-30 00:00:00
2      2017-10-30 00:00:00     2017-10-31 00:00:00
3      2017-10-31 00:00:00     2017-10-31 07:30:00
4      2017-10-31 14:41:00     2017-10-31 15:14:00
5      2017-10-31 17:13:00     2017-11-01 00:00:00
6      2017-11-01 00:00:00     2017-11-01 23:45:00
7      2017-11-02 03:13:00     2017-11-02 07:56:00
```

I need to group consecutive data into islands. The data is non-overlapping. This is done easily enough using this query:

```
;with Islands as
(
    SELECT
        min([From]) as [From]
        ,max([To]) as [To]
    FROM
    (
        select
            [From],
            [To],
            sum(startGroup) over (order by [From]) StartGroup
        from 
        (       
            SELECT 
                [From],
                [To],
                (case when [From] <= lag([To]) over (order by [From])
                                then 0
                                else 1
                        end) as StartGroup
                FROM dbo.DateTable
        ) IsNewIsland
    ) GroupedIsland
    group by StartGroup
)
select *
from Islands
```

And gives me these results:

```
From                    To                 Rows 
-----------------------------------------------------
2017-10-28 00:00:00     2017-10-31 07:30:00      1-3
2017-10-31 14:41:00     2017-10-31 15:14:00      4
2017-10-31 17:13:00     2017-11-01 23:45:00      5-6
2017-11-02 03:13:00     2017-11-02 07:56:00      7
```

The problem I have is that I need to modify the query to cap/split the islands once they have gotten enough records to be a certain total duration. This is an input/hardcoded value. The split includes the entire record, not splitting in the middle of a record's `From-To` range. As an example, I need to split islands to be ***27*** hours. This would give this result:

```
From                    To                       Rows 
-----------------------------------------------------
2017-10-29 00:00:00     2017-10-30 00:00:00      1
2017-10-30 00:00:00     2017-10-31 07:30:00      2-3
2017-10-31 17:13:00     2017-11-01 23:45:00      5-6
```

The first island was split because rows 1 and 2 alone created a 27 hour period. Rows 4 and 7 are not enough to create an island, so they are ignored.

I tried pulling this information via a `lag` function in the inner select to compute the "rolling duration" across rows, but it would not work on islands that spanned more than 2 rows because it would only track the last row's duration and I could not "carry" the calculation forward.

```
SELECT 
  [From],
  [To],
  (case when [From] <= lag([To]) over (order by [From]
                            then (datediff(minute, [From], [To]) + lag(datediff(minute, [From], [To])) over (order by [From]))
                            else datediff(minute, [From], [To])
                    end) as RollingDuration,
  (case when [From] <= lag([To]) over (order by [From])
                      then 0
                      else 1
          end) as StartGroup
FROM dbo.DateTable
```

Comment: i think first table is your input that you have and last is your expected output that you wish.can once explain the output requirement.

Comment: @KumarHarsh I need to split the larger islands by a certain value and ignore any island that is smaller than the same value. I included the row numbers and an explanation below the output table of how this would look. The output needs to include the two boundary timestamps of each valid island.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "least worst" way I can think of doing it is a "quirky update".  *(Google it, I honestly didn't make it up.)*

- http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/

  - Copy the data in to a new table with one or more additional (blank) fields
  - Use a CLUSTERED PRIMARY KEY to ensure the rows are updated in correct sequence
  - Use `UPDATE` and user variables to iterate through rows and store results of calculations

Using that I can start a new group if there is a gap, or a running total reaches 27 hours.  Then proceed as usual.

```
-- New table to work through
----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Addition [group_start] field (identifies groups, and useful data)
-- PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED to enforce the order rows will be processed
----------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE sample (
    id             INT,
    start          DATETIME,
    cease          DATETIME,
    group_start    DATETIME   DEFAULT(0),
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (group_start, start)   -- To force the order we will iterate the rows, and is useful in last step
);

INSERT INTO
    sample (
        id,
        start,
        cease
    )
VALUES
    (1,      '2017-10-28 00:00:00',     '2017-10-30 00:00:00'),
    (2,      '2017-10-30 00:00:00',     '2017-10-31 00:00:00'),
    (3,      '2017-10-31 00:00:00',     '2017-10-31 07:30:00'),
    (4,      '2017-10-31 14:41:00',     '2017-10-31 15:14:00'),
    (5,      '2017-10-31 17:13:00',     '2017-11-01 00:00:00'),
    (6,      '2017-11-01 00:00:00',     '2017-11-01 23:45:00'),
    (7,      '2017-11-02 03:13:00',     '2017-11-02 07:56:00')
;


-- Quirky Update
----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Update [group_start] to the start of the current group
-- -> new group if gap since previous row
-- -> new group if previous row took group to 27 hours
-- -> else same group as previous row
----------------------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @grp_start DATETIME = 0;

WITH
    lagged AS
(
    SELECT *, LAG(cease) OVER (ORDER BY group_start, start) AS lag_cease FROM sample
)
UPDATE
    lagged
SET
    @grp_start
        = group_start
            = CASE WHEN start <> lag_cease                     THEN start
                   WHEN start >= DATEADD(hour, 27, @grp_start) THEN start
                                                               ELSE @grp_start END
OPTION
    (MAXDOP 1)
;

-- Standard SQL to apply other logic
----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- MAX() OVER () to find end time of each group
-- WHERE to filter out any groups under 12 hours long
----------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *,
        MAX(cease) OVER (PARTITION BY group_start)    AS group_cease
    FROM
        sample
)
   bounded_groups
WHERE
   group_cease >= DATEADD(hour, 12, group_start)
;
```

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1bec5b3fe920c1affd58f23a11e280a0